# Fatal Error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object in register.php on line 102

Tags: php, sql

I uploaded everything in my folder to my FTP, then I went to go test the register function (register.php), and when I register, it gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object in       register.php on line 102
```

I checked everything, and made sure it was all fine.

Is there something wrong with the code?
Thanks.

```
$name3 = $odb -> query("SELECT `sitename` FROM `SiteConfig` LIMIT 1") -> fetchColumn(0);
$name2 = $odb -> query("SELECT `header` FROM `forgotconfig` LIMIT 1") -> fetchColumn(0);
$subject1 = $odb -> query("SELECT `Subject` FROM `forgotconfig` LIMIT 1") -> fetchColumn(0);
$subject = "Welcome To $name2";
$name1 = $odb -> query("SELECT `email` FROM `forgotconfig` LIMIT 1") -> fetchColumn(0);
```

Comment: The first line of what I posted.

Comment: One of you queries does not return the expected object.

Comment: probably query() failed and therefore returned FALSE instead of a result object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your queries is failing and the corresponding `$odb -> query()` is returning probably a boolean `false` `instead of an object.

Don't chain, but test your query result before using like object:

```
   $name3 = null;
   $result =  $odb -> query("SELECT `sitename` FROM `SiteConfig` LIMIT 1");
   if(!empty($result)) {
        $name3  = $result->fetchColumn(0);
   } else{
       //assuming PDO
       print_r($odb->errorInfo());
  }

   // rinse and repeat....
```

Just taking a random guess at which query is failing, without your schema or the exact DB error, I'd have no clue.

I'd start by adding some error handling.

Without that, I'd just start by picking the line with the error and checking the column and table name case to see if they match your DB.  Some DB's and some filesystesm have case sensitivity (sometimes in some like mysql this can be turned on/off).